# intel wireless 1000 bgn not working in debian/ubuntu

Tags: debian, wifi

First, I'm not an expert in Linux but I can fairly move and play around with the OS.

The problem in short is, I was able to find wireless networks, but when I try to authenticate it, network-manager keeps on asking me for my password. So it seems like it's not able to authenticate at all.

In Windows 7 everything's working OK.

So what i've done so far is…

- I have installed firmware-iwlwifi_0.28_all.deb and was able to detect wireless networks
- I reconfigured my wifi to wpa2 personal, it does not work. I reconfigured it to use wep 128, it doesn't work either
- I tried to install ubuntu, and it poses the same problem :(

Here's my PC information:

Asus K42JA. I used the 64 bit installer of Debian Live 6.0.1 and Ubuntu 10.10

Can you help me with this? I can provide you log information, but I don't know where to find them. :(

UPDATE:
here's the content of my `/etc/network/interfaces`.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`lsmod` (iw* related information)

```
iwlagn   73139   0
iwlcore  77810   1   iwlagn
```

here's what's inside `daemon.log`. Hope you can help me fix this problem. I just bought this laptop :(

```
Apr  4 18:43:07 sophia NetworkManager[1849]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  associating -> disconnected
Apr  4 18:43:07 sophia NetworkManager[1849]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  disconnected -> scanning
Apr  4 18:43:08 sophia wpa_supplicant[1879]: Trying to associate with 00:24:01:1a:48:35 (SSID='Funshine' freq=2437 MHz)
Apr  4 18:43:08 sophia NetworkManager[1849]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  scanning -> associating
Apr  4 18:43:17 sophia NetworkManager[1849]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long.
Apr  4 18:43:17 sophia NetworkManager[1849]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: 5 -> 6 (reason 0)
Apr  4 18:43:17 sophia NetworkManager[1849]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): asking for new secrets
Apr  4 18:43:17 sophia NetworkManager[1849]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant connection state:  associating -> disconnected
Apr  4 18:43:18 sophia wpa_supplicant[1879]: Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.
```

Comment: Could you paste your `/etc/network/interfaces`, minus the passwords of course? :-) Also, the relevant parts of `lsmod`. What tools are you using to manage the wireless?

Comment: not much information... updated the details above.

Comment: added daemon.log details

Comment: consider trying also with `/etc/network/interfaces`. It might help to debug the problem.

Comment: I already tried /etc/network/interfaces, and still no sweet glory from it. I even switched to wicd... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a buggy driver paired with old kernel. Using the latest kernel (2.6.38) solves the problem.

I installed Ubuntu 11.04, and everything is normal again.

Edited:

Trying to improve my answer here. Intel Wireless 1000 BGN stopped working after 2.6.38. Apparently there is a setting in iwlwifi needed to deactivate for it to work again.

To fix this, create/edit any file under `/etc/modprobe.d/` (i.e. `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`).

Then, add this in the end.

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
```

For more information regarding this, refer [here](http://bugzilla.intellinuxwireless.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2325) or [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?s=c95251665c334aa13d398a5c0f3f5c7c&t=1862484&page=8).

Answer (score 1):

If that is really the entire content of `/etc/network/interfaces`, you need to add your wireless interfaces there. You didn't state what methods you are using to manage the wireless, but whatever it is is clearly not writing to `/etc/network/interfaces`, which is necessary, as far as I know. This file is where all the network interfaces and configuration information, including passwords, is defined. See any Debian networking tutorial. First take a look at `man interfaces`.

This [network tutorial](http://wiki.debian.org/iwlagn) looks relevant. You'll need to add wlan0 to your /etc/network/interfaces with appropriate configuration. They left that part out.

Comment: network-manager is the one managing my connection, in my other laptops, i didn't configure anything in my /etc/network/interfaces. if that's the case, i'll to put something in it and will let you know.

Comment: With network manager, you don't need to configure /etc/network/interfaces unless you'd rather have it managed by the system and not rely on a user logging in to be online.  I might do that for a stationary server, but probably not for a mobile laptop or even a desktop.

Comment: @Marc: I don't know anything about network-manager, but are you saying that you have successfully used it to configure your network with your other laptops without writing anything to /etc/network/interfaces? If so, I'm surprised. EDIT: having looked at the documentation, apparently that is how it works. However, if it not working for you, using the standard tools is a reasonable alternative, imo.

Comment: @penguin: I see. Personally, I prefer to do things as transparently as possible, not use some magic piece of software. But your mileage may vary.

Comment: @penguin: after a little googling, this might be a buggy driver. Have you tried with a newer kernel? Are you currently using the default 2.6.32?

Comment: @penguin: firmware-iwlwifi 0.29 is in unstable. It is worth trying. [Here](http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/current/changelog) is the changelog.

Comment: yes i'm using 2.6.32, the default of debian 6.0.1.

the weird part is, I tried live cds from Ubuntu 10.10, Linux Mint 8. Still no luck... I know they are using older kernels.

Comment: @Marc: Ok. Sorry, I see I've been addressing the wrong person above. Have you tried 0.29 and more recent kernels yet? That is probably your best shot at this point. 2.6.32 is quite old. Using newer kernels is probably your best shot at this point. Also, this forum is not the best place for debugging. Have you tried asking on a more relevant forum, like one dedicated to linux networking or even a ml for the driver in question?

Comment: Thanks, thanks for you patience in looking into this. That's one of my checklist, I will try wheezy version of debian later with more updated kernels. Will let you know :)

Comment: @Marc: You can use squeeze with a newer kernel. It is not usually a problem.